# Gcc include search paths

Tags: c++, gcc, ubuntu-16.04, eclipse-cdt

Hi recently I upgraded gcc to 9.1,but I installed in custom path. All the other dependency libraries i use is also installed in that path. I had set PATH and LIBRARY_PATH to this folder. Whatever previous versions i was using it is still there in system path. Now when I compile my program first it is searching include files in the system path then later my custom path. How can i make so first include search priority to be given to the custom path.

And also i am using eclipse on Ubuntu for development, it is not referring g++ to the new path. Still considering old path. How can i rectify this? Invoking g++, gcc, gdb points to the new path

Comment: Before downvoting can you tell me the reason why

Comment: Explaining downvotes often winds up starting a fight with the writer of the downvoted question so many refrain from explaining their reasoning. You may have better luck creating a cross compiler project. I found them easier to configure with the correct paths.